# Can't gem install Celluloid using Rubinius 2.0.0

Tags: ruby, rvm, rubinius, celluloid

I have rvm set to

```
# .rvmrc
rvm use rbx-2.0.0-rc1
```

and it sets the version correctly

```
$ ruby -v
rubinius 2.0.0rc1 (1.8.7 release 2012-11-02 JI) [x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.1]
```

when I try to

```
$ gem install celluloid -v '0.12.3'
```

I get the error

```
ERROR:  Error installing celluloid:
celluloid requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2.
```

Whats the problem? I know Celluloid supports Rubinius because it is the recommended interpreter. https://github.com/celluloid/celluloid

Update:
I figured it out thanks to this link https://gist.github.com/4123305

I needed to pass the -X19 flag

```
ruby -X19 -S bundle
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out thanks to this link https://gist.github.com/4123305

I needed to pass the -X19 flag

```
ruby -X19 -S bundle
```

Comment: this is no more supported in master version of rubinius, it has to be specified during compilation.

Answer (score 2):

You can force this at compilation level:

```
rvm install rbx --1.9
```

now all uses of rbx will work by default in 1.9 mode.